# Android and fairly large SQLite datafiles

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm starting an Android project, a port from an existing iPhone project I've completed.

I have a fairly large read-only SQLite database, about 100Mb in all. It's called "mydata.sqlite". Where do I place this in my Eclipse workspace? It's too big for "assets".

Next, how do I best get at the file? I would think to try (handling exceptions later) something like:

```
SQLiteDatabase myDatabase = null;
myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

But I would then need the path string `myPath` and since I don't know where to put the resource I don't know what this needs to be.

Can I put "mydata.sqlite" into "res/raw" (once I create "raw" in Eclipse?) and then reference it as a resource with "R.raw.mydata"?

I would very much appreciate some direct help here, rather than a reference to a tutorial. I have checked tons of these, including those that are already cited here on stackoverflow. I've also gone through the "Notepad" project in the Android developer documents. However these and the documentation typically consider only new, empty or small databases that aren't always persistent. This should be a simple thing and given the time I've spent already it is perhaps easier to ask.

Thanking you kindly in advance for your assistance.

Comment: There's a 50MB limit (I think) on applications downloaded from the market. Why would you possibly need that big of a database?

Comment: @Falmarri: My reasons aren't that relevant, but I can say the database is an essential component of the app. The file size limits, even if I get the database under 50MB uncompressed, are still annoying. (See @SteD.)

Comment: Well I really don't see a legitimate purpose for a 100MB database on a phone.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried to include such a big DB in my app before.

One solution to your question might be renaming your `mydata.sqlite` to something like `mydata.jpg` to avoid the file from being compressed by aapt, which after you can put it in asset folder and access it from there.

> Any compressed asset file with
>   an uncompressed size of over 1 MB
>   cannot be read from the APK.
>   [[source]](http://ponystyle.com/blog/2010/03/26/dealing-with-asset-compression-in-android-apps/)

Edit: Seems like your best bet now is to retrieve the data in small chunk off a web server when needed? Found [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ce211e11336cfdb4/e0622913f3fcb9ec?lnk=gst&q=large+database#e0622913f3fcb9ec), check out mjc147's solution and Romain Guy from Google explains about the 1mb limitation.

Comment: Thank you for your post and link. (1) The database is an essential component of the app. (2) It will still need to be compressed as part of the app (so that if/when it is downloaded it does not take an age). (e.g. The iPhone app compresses to about 28Mb, and will be cut further so that it's under the 3G limit of 20Mb. I digress.) It sounds like the APK limit is a major barrier for me...?

Comment: PS - your point about the APK limit does shed some light on why there's little (if any) documentation on managing large files for Android. :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit and follow up. I'm reluctantly thinking the same thing about servers - that's a no-go for me, the database needs to be local. Hmm. Hmm... There's a strict limit on the size of the file, but is there a limit on the number of files?! If not, can each of these (now txt files?) go the assets folder?

Comment: @SK9, that's one of the possible solution, split and put the SQL statements which required to build the DB into /res/raw (which you can refer it with R.raw.<filename>.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you are putting a 100MB asset in your .apk, you are going to end up with an app that is too big to publish on Market.

Comment: The limit on an app sizes is 50MB, so yes it would be too large. I can cut the database down for this platform.

Answer (score 0):

I did it once with a 35MB SQLite database. What I did:

1.) I used a Windows Tool (I think it was TotalCommander) to split that *.db  file into pieces of 1MB.

2.) I've put them in the assets folder.

3.) In my database helper class I moved these pieces together during first startup.

It worked perfect and was fast enough.

What you should think about:

1.) At one point you have 3* 50MB during startup on the internal storage so please consider using SD card for your database.

2.) At one point during update of your apps you have 4* 50MB on your device...

Regards
hjw

Comment: Thank you for your post. I'm not sure what you mean by "3). ... moved these pieces together ..." or why you should (if I understand correctly). A file that is larger than 1MB when uncompressed is ignored by the APK. One question you might be able to help with: If I break up an SQLite database into (say) 5 pieces and don't bring them together, is there a good way to index these? [I'm thinking having a sixth SQLite database to index these...?]

Comment: The 1MB filesize limit was the reason to split the file in several pieces. During first startup I copied these pieces together to form the *.db file. This *.db file was created in /data/data/<package>/databases and worked as expected. To your question: Never had to create more than one database on a device. It might work.

Comment: OK, so you used SQLite to combine several smaller databases in your /assets folder and dumped the result in /databases. The combined database will then be larger than the 1MB limit, you're saying this limit does not apply to /databases? That I can read it whole from there?